# WordPress hardcode Excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to have just one hard-coded Excerpt in word-press for all posts and pages?

What i have read so far is that i need to change index.php and archive.php file.

But am not sure whats the best way of doing this. Or can i build a function for it?

I want the same Excerpt for all posts/pages.

Or if there is some plug-in that does this.

The code i have found that i need to replace is

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Replace to

```
<?php if (function_exists(‘has_excerpt’) && has_excerpt()) the_excerpt(); ?>
```

But i cant find in what files i have checked my index.php,page.php,header.php

I am using TwentyEleven as theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a common excerpt then just hard code it wherever you want to display it.

Instead of `the_excerpt();` just write your hard coded excerpt for example

```
 <div>This is my sample static excerpt</div>
```

That's it.

Comment: Is it possible to check if it works? Like how to fetch the Excerpt ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples

```
<?php
// Get particular post's excerpt
$my_post = get_post('some-Post-ID');
echo $my_post->post_excerpt;
?>
```

or

```
<?php
if ( is_category() || is_archive() ) {
    the_excerpt();
}
?>
```

But I believe you need same excerpt for all your posts hence you should print a common static excerpt.